# Error al instalar Ruby on Rails

Tags: nodejs, ruby-on-rails

Esta es la 5 vez que intento instalar Ruby on Rails, pero siempre me da errores cómo Gema requerida, o al instalarlas cuando no están me dice que las gemas están corrompidas. También me dice que corra el comando ridk install pero cuando se inicia una descarga me dice Download... FAILED y se llena la consola de eso.
El error más común en todas las instalaciones que hice es
rails server

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
c:/verst windows/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
        from c:/verst windows/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que muestra te dice, en la segunda línea, que no tienes instalado *runtime* alguno para *JavaScript*:

> Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See
>   https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.

Para eliminar el error debes instalar un *runtime* en tu máquina, por ejemplo uno muy común es [*Node.js*](https://nodejs.org/en/download/); sin embargo puedes elegir cualquier otro de los indicados en el [enlace sugerido por el error](https://github.com/rails/execjs).